# Schedule AWS instance to Auto Start/Shutdown

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to run a very light ruby script once a day and then shutdown my Elastic Cloud instance on AWS in order to reduce its costs.

Is it possible to schedule an instance to auto-start once a day, run a script for one hour and then shut-down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://alestic.com/2011/11/ec2-schedule-instance) covers how to use auto-scaling to launch your instance for a short time to run a job.

As for the job itself, you can trigger it's execution on startup by any of the methods suitable to your OS/environment. Some are listed [on this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of Lambda and CloudWatch.

Please refer: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/